# JSF Not working

Tags: jsf, tomcat, facelets

I want to use JSF for a project (i just started learning), and i startwd with this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<head>
   <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>h:inputText example</h2>
   <hr />
   <h:form>
      <h3>Read-Only input text box</h3>
      <h:inputText value="Hello World!" readonly="true"/>
      <h3>Read-Only input text box</h3>
      <h:inputText value="Hello World"/>
   </h:form>
</body>

</html>
```

But when i load the page, i can see only texts, the input fields do not appear.i

As a server i use Apache Tomcat 7.0 with Eclipse IDE

Comment: Lots of questions here: How is your web.xml configured? What is the extension of this file? Have you put all the LIBs on your WEB-INF/libs folder?

Comment: I think you should use h:body

Comment: this file is an .xhtml file . and my libs folder is empty(shouldn't the ide add the libs when i create the new project? )


web xml looks like this 
'(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TrafficSystem</display-name>

</web-app>)'

Answer (score 1):

Currently your inputText is not interpreted (when you open your webpages source in your browser, you will find the plain `h:inputText` tag in there).

Make sure, that your `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` are correctly filled.
(e.g. your `web.xml` includes the Faces Servlet, something like ...)

```
....
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

While Application Server like JBoss usually bring Libraries for JSF pre-installed, for the Apache Tomcat Web-Container you have to add the Libraries for JSF - either through manually copying the needed JARs into Tomcats `/lib` - directory or via configuring your IDE to package them into your projects WAR being delivered to the tomcat (they will be stored in your JARs `/WEB-INF/lib` directory).

Eclipse WTP e.g. has under right-click "project properties" -> "deployment assembly" an dialog for configuring those.

Comment: Why no mapping on `*.xhtml`?

Comment: Good question. The current project I copy'n'pasted the code from uses jsf as extension ;-) A mapping to *.xhtml is of course possible, too.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/21227775#21227775